# How can I more efficiently render Mathjax content?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I have hundreds of equations on a page. I run

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
  }
});
```

But I see `Processing math: 100%` and `Typesetting math: 100%`. Any way to stop it with a button or something?

Comment: A self-contained example that exhibits the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Try this: https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/ KaTeX is made by Khan Accademy to be a more robust math renderer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** If you want to turn off preprocessor previews and the fast previews. Try setting your configuration to this -

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "fast-preview": {disabled:true},
    tex2jax: {
      preview: "none",
      inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]
    }
});
```

**2)** If you add below script to your page BEFORE the `<script>` that loads MathJax.js then the processing messages will not be shown (but other messages like file and font loading will still be shown).

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      showProcessingMessages: false
    });
</script>
```

If you want to eliminate ALL messages, then use -

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      messageStyle: "none"
    });
</script>
```

**3)** There isn't a predefined way, but you could override the Message.File() method and cause the file messages to have a visibility time of 0 (so they will be removed immediately).  Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Message.File = function (file) {
        var root = MathJax.Ajax.config.root;
        if (file.substr(0,root.length) === root) {file = "[MathJax]"+file.substr(root.length)}
        return this.Set("Loading "+file,null,0);
      }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML">   </script>
```

This still means that the messages will be saved in the log, but they won't show up on the screen.

**4)** [Hiding content until typesetting is complete](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Hiding-content-until-typesetting-is-complete)

Hope either of above all solutions does the trick and satisfy what you want. Thanks

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.